# Is it possible to prove the quantifier-shift fallacy is not valid using natural deduction?

Tags: proof-writing, first-order-logic

I am aware that, in general, sentences of the form  $\exists \forall$ logically imply  $\forall \exists$, but not vice versa. An example of the latter case is:

$((\forall x \exists y : loves(x,y)) \nvdash (\exists y \forall x : loves(x,y)))$. (**1**)

I have found [proof by counter example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608841/show-forall-x-exists-yrx-y-exists-x-forall-yrx-y-are-not-logically-equi?rq=1) but no direct proof.

The [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20logic%2C%20a%20deduction,explicit%20inference%20rule%20for%20this.) provides a relationship between $\vdash$ and $\implies$.

For example we can prove: *If I am loved by everybody then everybody loves someone*.

$((\exists y \forall x : loves(x,y)) \vdash  (\forall x \exists y : loves(x,y)))$. (**2**)

using the corresponding sentence  (**3**)

$((\exists y \forall x : loves(x,y)) \implies  (\forall x \exists y : loves(x,y)))$. (**3**)

I do not know how to write a sentence with $\implies$ that corresponds to (**1**). Is is possible to prove the invalidity expressed in (**1**) using natural deduction?

Comment: The natural deduction rules tell you how to prove **instances** of $\vdash$. To prove a **non-instance** of $\vdash$, you need to work "one level higher" and prove things *about* the natural deduction rules, not simply use them. One way to do this is via the [**soundness theorem**](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/logic/soundness.html) and an appropriate model construction.

Comment: If I love all women on Earth, why does that imply all men love at least one woman?

Comment: @SenZen I think that I got it right at last!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Natural deduction can only be used to show that inferences are valid, not that inferences are invalid. And as you correctly point out, $\forall x \exists y \phi(x,y) \not \vdash \exists y \forall x \phi(x,y)$ (which holds) is not equivalent to $\forall x \exists y \phi(x,y) \vdash \neg \exists y \forall x \phi(x,y)$ (which doesn't hold). To show $\not \vdash$ without a countermodel, you'd have to argue about the non-existence of derivations, which is tricky.